# Get cropped canvas toBlob function not working in safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, safari, cropperjs

Below function working fine in firefox, chrome, mobile everything works fine for cropping image and then ajax called. But in Tab - Safari browser, its not working. Please help.

```
        cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob(function (blob) {
            alert("aaa");
        });
```

Comment: canvas.toBlob() isn't supported on Safari. This library solved the same problem I was having https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob